# NullPointerException, multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception

I am new to Java and I am doing a project for my computer science class. 
I have to add details to a multi-dimensional array. Here is my code

```
public class Login {
public static String[][] all_users = new String[50][13];

public static void main(String[] args){ //throws FileNotFoundException {
    welcome();
    userSearch user_info = new userSearch();
    user_info.fileSearch(all_users);
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = userIn.next();
    switch (input) {
        case "1":
            user_info.viewUserList(all_users);
            break;
        case "2":
            AddUser.addDetails();
            break;
        case "3":
            System.out.println("please enter administrator password to       modify or delete contents: ");
            Pass.getPassword();
            break;
    }
}

private static void welcome() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the user information profiler. \n here are your options, please enter one of the numbers: ");
    System.out.println("1) view a list of all current users. /n 2) Add user details to the list."
            + "/n 3) if you know the administrator password and wish to modify or delete user details.");
    System.out.println("Enter a choice now: ");
}
```

}

and the Add user class

```
public class AddUser extends Login {
public static void addDetails(){
System.out.println("Please add details for a new user: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < all_users.length; i++){
        if (all_users [i][0] == null){
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                switch(all_users[i][j]) {
                    case "1":
                        System.out.println("input first name: ");
                        all_users[i][0] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        System.out.println("input last name: ");
                        all_users[i][1] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        System.out.println("input phone number(xxxyyyzzzz): ");
                        all_users[i][2] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        System.out.println("input email address: ");
                        all_users[i][3] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        System.out.println("input Apartment Number: ");
                        all_users[i][4] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        System.out.println("input Street Adress: ");
                        all_users[i][5] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        System.out.println("input City: ");
                        all_users[i][6] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        System.out.println("input State (ex. NJ): ");
                        all_users[i][7] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        System.out.println("input Zip Code: ");
                        all_users[i][8] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        System.out.println("input Vehicle Type(ex. luxury, sport): ");
                        all_users[i][9] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        System.out.println("input Vehicle Model(ex. Toyota, Nissan: ");
                        all_users[i][10] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "12":
                        System.out.println("input Vehicle Color: ");
                        all_users[i][11] = scan.next();
                        break;
                    case "13":
                        System.out.println("input License Plate: ");
                        all_users[i][12] = scan.next();
                        break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I get a NullPointerException

```
switch(all_users[i][j]) {
```

and on

```
AddUser.addDetails();
```

Why is this happening, and how can i fix it?

Comment: What is all_users and why do you think AddUser would have access to it?

Comment: all_users is a 2d array that stores information from a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (all_users [i][0] == null){
    for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
```

You're entering only if `[i][0]` is `null` but then you're switching `[i][j]` when j = 0. So you're first value tested is `null`

replace

```
for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
```

with

```
for (int j = 1; j < 13; j++){
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, that does not seem to fix the error. Regardless, if i change to j=1, then i cant write to index [i][0] of the array. So that would not have helped. but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Before your switch add the writing to the index zero... Do not forget to accept the answer :)